# How to use the CRUD method in my code, but prevent endpoint access

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-rest

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   private String name;
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
   @Secured("ADMIN")
   @Override
   <S extends Test> S save(S entity);
}

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void something() {
        myEntityRepository.save(new MyEntity());
    }
}
```

Note : User-related security settings are already finished.

So, My question is i hope to use `save`method at my code without any authority, but prevent public access to `save` by client.

If i tried like above example, i can't use too.
How can i do that? Is it possible?

In shortly,

```
Access for Controller to save -> "/" : Permit All
Access for Data Rest's save Endpoint -> "/metrics" : hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for your scenario if i understand your question.

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/metrics").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.toString())
            .anyRequest().permitAll()

}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles(ADMIN.toString())
            .and()
            .withUser("guest").password("guest").roles(GUEST.toString());
}
```

}